# Comparator not applicable for arguments

Tags: java, compare

I get the following error in this

```
Collection<RatingDTO> ratings = question.
RatingsComparator comparator = new RatingsComparator();
Collections.sort(ratings, comparator);
```

**Error:**

```
The method sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (Collection<RatingDTO>, RatingsComparator)
```

**RatingDTO**

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class RatingDTO {
    private Double value;
    private Integer weekNumber;
    private Double total = 0d;
    private int numberOfAnswers = 0;

    public void addRating(Integer rating) {
        numberOfAnswers++;
        total += rating;
        value = total / numberOfAnswers;
    }
}
```

**RatingsComparator**

```
public class RatingsComparator implements Comparator<RatingDTO> {
    public enum Order {
        WEEK_NUMBER, AVG_RATING, AMOUNT_OF_ANSWERS
    }

    private Order sortingBy = Order.WEEK_NUMBER;

    @Override
    public int compare(RatingDTO rating1, RatingDTO rating2) {
        switch (sortingBy) {
        case WEEK_NUMBER:
            return rating1.getWeekNumber().compareTo(rating2.getWeekNumber());
        case AVG_RATING:
            return rating1.getValue().compareTo(rating2.getValue());
        case AMOUNT_OF_ANSWERS:
            return rating1.getTotal().compareTo(rating2.getTotal());
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("Practically unreachable code, can't be thrown");
    }
}
```

What am I forgetting? Thanks in advance for enlightning me.

Comment: A `Collection` is not a `List`.

Comment: What is this line doing? `Collection<RatingDTO> ratings = question.`

Comment: @Alexandre Santos, it's the origin of the Ratings, from another DTO. Nothing to worry about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Collection` is not sortable by default (for example, a `HashSet` is an unordered `Collection`).

That is why `Collections.sort(...)` takes a `List` and not a `Collection`.

Hence, as said by Sotirios Delimanolis, it will work only if `ratings` is a `List<RatingDTO>`.

Javadoc about `List` :

> An ordered collection (also known as a sequence). The user of this interface has precise control over where in the list each element is inserted

Comment: Ahh so need to convert the Collection<RatingDTO> into List<RatingDTO>.
**Thanks**